# Stack and queue error in my program

Tags: python, linked-list, stack, queue

I'm trying to sort out my program from 2 hours, But every time i'm getting the same error.

I'm working on `Stack, Queue and Linked List` program using python.

Please help me, Whats wrong here in my code?

```
import random

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, other=None):
        self.other = other
        self.next = next
        self.previous = previous

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.other)

class List(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, value):
        newNode = Node(value)

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode

        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode

    def __str__(self):
        someString = ""
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            someString = someString + current.other
            current = current.next
            return someString

class Queue(List):

    def enqueue(self, value):
        self.append(value)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        return temp

class Stack(List):

    def push(self, value):
        self.append(value)

    def pop(self):
        self.temp = self.tail
        self.tail = self.tail.previous
        return self.temp

def main():

    list1 = List()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        list1.append(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))
        print(list1)

    queue = Queue()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        queue.enqueue(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))

    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(queue.dequeue)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        print("----------------------------------------")
        stack = Stack()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        stack.push(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))

    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(stack.pop())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Here is Screenshot of my output:**

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kiwq.png)

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: in `Node`'s `__init__` method, where is `other` and `previous` supposed to come from?

Comment: You should put the error messages into your question in a code block, **not** as a screenshot. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion.
The output seems to be good.

```
import random

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, other=None):
        self.other = other
        self.next = None # next -> None
        self.previous = None # previous -> None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.other)

class List(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, value):
        newNode = Node(value)

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode

        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode

    def __str__(self):
        someString = ""
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            someString = someString + current.other
            current = current.next
        return someString # declease indent (get it out of the while loop)

class Queue(List):

    def enqueue(self, value):
        self.append(value)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        if self.head is None: # add
            self.tail = None # add
        else: # add
            self.head.previous = None # add (cut the link to the dequeued node)
        return self.temp # temp -> self.temp

class Stack(List):

    def push(self, value):
        self.append(value)

    def pop(self):
        self.temp = self.tail
        self.tail = self.tail.previous
        if self.tail is None: # add
            self.head = None # add
        else: # add
            self.tail.next = None # add (cut the link to the popped node)
        return self.temp

def main():

    list1 = List()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        list1.append(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))
        print(list1)

    queue = Queue()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        queue.enqueue(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))

    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(queue.dequeue()) # dequeue -> dequeue()

    # I have no idea why this for is here.
    # for i in range(0, 10):
    print("----------------------------------------") # adjust indent
    stack = Stack() # adjust indent
    for i in range(0, 100):
        stack.push(str(random.randrange(0, 100)))

    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(stack.pop())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```